# how to run arm v8a apps in android x86_64

Tags: android, arm

I tried installing libhoudini but still im not able to run ARM apps especially the ARM-v8a apps in prime OS (0.4.5 Final release). Is there any other way to solve it

Comment: Why not search online? This is my first result by serching on Google: https://hatwars.com/now-you-can-run-arm-binaries-in-x86-android-emulators/

Comment: Did not help at all

Comment: I still have the same issue